# Are the two definitions of local objects in the context of left Bousfield localization equivalent?

Tags: homotopy-theory, localization, model-categories

Given a simplicial model category $\mathcal{M}$ and a set $S$ of morphisms in it, we can define the concept of $S$-local objects. In nLab page (below [Definition 3.2](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bousfield+localization+of+model+categories#LocHasToBeSLoc)), a fibrant object $X\in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{M})$ is $S$-local if for any map $f:A\rightarrow B$ in $S$, the induced morphism $\mathbb{R}f^*:\mathbb{R}\mathrm{Map}(B,X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\mathrm{Map}(A,X)$ between simplicial sets is an isomorphism in $\mathrm{Ho}(sSet)$, which is also equivalent to say $Qf^*:\mathrm{Map}(QB,X)\rightarrow \mathrm{Map}(QA,X)$ is a weak equivalence in $sSet$ where $QA$ and $QB$ are cofibrant replacement. It's also the definition accepted by Clark Barwick in the paper *On (Enriched) Left Bousfield Localization of Model Categories*
([Definition 2.6](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2067)).

But in the book *Model Categories and Their Localizations* of Philip S. Hirschhorn (Definition 3.1.4),  he requires $f^*:\mathrm{Map}(B,X)\rightarrow \mathrm{Map}(A,X)$ is a weak equivalence and do not pass to cofibrant replacements. I want to know whether the two definitions are equivalent.

When I try to prove the equivalence, it seems I need to prove for a trivial fibration $p:QA\rightarrow A$ where $QA$ is cofibrant, the map $p^*:\mathrm{Map}(A,X)\rightarrow \mathrm{Map}(QA,X)$ is a weak equivalence. But I can not prove it.

Comment: I think that Hirschhorn's definition is the same. This follows from the definition of a function complex. The thing is, it does not matter how we define them; they are homotopy invariant in both arguments. In particular, Hirschhorn gives a construction of such complex via (co)simplicial resolution of both arguments, which essentially means that we take cofibrant replacement in the first argument and fibrant in the second one ($\S 17.3$). Frankly, Hirschhorn's exposition is too involved for me, so I prefer Chapter 5 in Hovey's book, where you can find an analogous construction via framings.

Comment: @GrishaTaroyan Thanks! It's all right. Sorry for mistaking Hirschhorn's definition of homotopy function complex.

Answer (score 2):

The two Map's are different (and have different notations in the respective sources).

nLab's Map (denoted by $C(-,-)$ there) is the hom-object given by the simplicial enrichment of the category $C$.
In particular, $\def\rdf{{\bf R}}\def\Map{{\rm Map}}\rdf\Map$ is the derived hom-object functor.

Hirschhorn's Map (denoted by $\def\map{{\rm map}}\map$ there) is the homotopy function complex defined using Reedy (co)fibrant resolutions of the source and/or target.

The very point of simplicial model categories is that $\rdf\Map$ and $\map$ are weakly equivalent functors.
See Example 17.1.4 in Hirschhorn's book and references therein.

Thus, the two definitions of left Bousfield localizations are equivalent.